# oracle 11g odbc drivers installation on windows 7 oracle odbc driver with the same name already exists

Tags: database, windows, oracle, odbc

these are the steps:

1. downloaded: instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.3.0.zip
2. extracted to c:\instant_client_11_2
3. downloaded: instantclient-odbc-windows.x64-11.2.0.3.0.zip
4. extracted to c:\instant_client_11_2 (the same dir from step 2)
5. via cmd: odbc_install
6. getting "oracle odbc driver with the same name already exists"

i've tried with instantclient-basiclite-windows.x64-11.2.0.3.0 in step 1 instead. getting the same error

Interesting facts:

- i had the XE edition installed too, uninstalled it, deleted manually the C:\oracleXE folder, rebooted, retried steps 1-6 and still no joy. As far as i can tell there is no other oracle product (besides java) running on my machine.
- Using windows 7

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> via cmd *launched as administrator*: odbc_install

This should do the trick and print `Oracle ODBC Driver is installed successfully`